# "[Иван](,) с одной стороны(,) и [Петр](,) с другой стороны(,)" - обособление

Tags: пунктуация

***Фирма "Вязаные Веники"(,) с одной стороны(,) и гр. Растакойтов Имярек Батькович(,) с другой(,) заключили настоящий Договор...***

*Умоляю, сначала - как надо и **почему** (лучше - своими словами), всю лирику и философию - по желанию, но после ответа. Искать по Интернету я и сам умею и за свою жизнь написал не одну сотню таких фраз. Меня интересует трактовка данного случая, т.е. прежде всего - грамматический разбор.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне нравится Ваш вопрос!
Со мной будут спорить, но в этом случае запятые не нужны совсем, так как в предложении речь идёт непосредственно о двух "сторонах", которые заключили Договор. Выражения "с одной стороны", "с другой стороны" не являются вводными.

Comment: ОК, мнение понятно.

Comment: Катя, я с Вами согласна.

Comment: Очень рада, спасибо, Лара!

Comment: Короче, других мнений нет?
Жаль...  
Мне всегда казалось, что тут какое-то недоразумение с этими сторонами. Никогда не воспринимал эти "стороны" буквально.